# How to run a PHP file in a scheduled task (Windows Task Scheduler)

Tags: php, windows, scheduled-tasks

How can I create a scheduled task to run a PHP file?
Yes, I filled out everything in the scheduled task, but it still doesn't work.

> Run: "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\WEB\4w_website\save.php"
>
> Start in: "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\WEB\4w_website"

It just opens the PHP file in Notepad.

I gave the correct user name and pwd.

Please help me..

Answer (score 70):

The Run command should be

```
C:\Path\to\php.exe -f "C:\Path\to\file.php"
```

From the command line help of php.exe:

```
-f         Parse and execute <file>.
```

Comment: Isn't the `-f` optional?

Comment: I don't think so, but I haven't tested with recent PHP versions.

Answer (score 16):

I just wrote a `.bat` file that does the work **file.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
php.exe -f "C:\code\cust.php"
```

And put it in the Schedule Tasks like this:

Run: `C:\code\file.bat`

Start in: `C:\code\`

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. Just one note, that path to `php.exe` should be full.

Comment: If my scheduled tasks take 5 mins to run, how long will it take 5 tasks  input in this way to run? will it be just over 5 mins or 25 mins. i.e it waits till complete?

Comment: @Mikeys4u, Let us know what's the answer you had after trying.

Comment: @Pacerier If you use the word START at the beginning of each bat command this will make the task run in a different process (thread). Therefore the answer to above is without using START it will take 25 mins as each is run one after the other, or if you do use START then it should be 5 mins....

Comment: @Mikeys4u, Which system did you try that on?

Comment: @Pacerier This was run on windows 7, scheduled tasks, and Plesk

Answer (score 6):

If you running php scripts, in most of cases script awaiting to be runned in current folder.
That mean you must set up folder each your action, use field "**Start In**".

Example:

```
Run: C:\php\php.exe 
Arguments: -f C:\web\myscript.php
```

**Do not forget:**

```
 Start in: C:\web\
```

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you don't have PHP files associated with the EXE.

You can do this **My Computer** > **Tools** > **Folder Options** > **File Types**. If nothing else, this can also help you verify your settings for them.

Otherwise, you can specify **"C:\path\to\php.exe [file]"** in the task.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did:

1. PHP file

   ```
   <?php my code goes here ?>
   ```

   *Note if you are using HTTP API/CURL in CLI use `dl("php_curl.dll");`

   this loads curl into cli
2. Now I added PHP to windows path variable, this can be done from My computer, properties, advanced settings, environment variables, new
3. Next I created a .bat file, simply open a notepad & type code below and save as myfile.bat

   ```
   @ECHO OFF
   php -f d:\wamp\www\V3\task.php
   ```

   [This site](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/write-simple-batch-bat-file/) might help you on .bat file syntax.
4. Now create a new scheduled task on windows & call the above .bat file as source,

Answer (score 2):

#### For those people that can't able to make @Tomalak's answer work:

Check if there are spaces () in your directory. If it does, you need to enclose them with `"`.

```
"C:\Path\to php file\php.exe" -f "C:\Path\to php file\file.php"
```

And if it still did not work, check your `file.php` if there are included files in it.

```
include("file2.php"); /* OR */
include_once("file2.php");
```

Remove it. And if the included file in your `file.php` is really needed, try to move the code/script from that included file to your main file.

Comment: i tried like this but it does not work for me. i create a bat file and one php file. The php file contains include two php files. nothing fix my problem

Comment: @Karthi - move the codes from those two files onto your main file. Unfortunately, included files are not being read with this method

Answer (score -2):

I think, you must execute your PHP script via URL.
you can write batch script for execute URL.
Why you don't write backend script in other language such as batch script, vbscript or etc.

Comment: Why you don't write backend script in PHP?