# Automatically send SQL table contents to an email address

Tags: php, mysql, automation, phpmyadmin, timed-events

I've setup a flash game that reports scores via php to a table in a MySQL database that I access through phpMyAdmin.

I'd like to be able to set it up so that at 10am on the 22nd December for eg, the system emails me a backup of the database so I have a hard copy of the data on the game's closing date.

Is this possible? Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks a lot,
-Ben

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are hosting on a linux server you can use cron to run a php script that will send the email with the info that you need. You can find more info [here](http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/php/running-php-cron-jobs-regular-scheduled-tasks-in-php-172/)

If you are on a windows server you can use the task schedule. You can read about it [here](http://drupal.org/node/31506) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295386/how-to-run-a-php-file-in-schedule-task).