# How do I run a PHP script using windows schedule task?

Tags: php, windows-7, scheduled-tasks

I have installed localhost/server in my machine and I need to run a php script using windows schedule task. how do I add path in "Actions" tab in schedule task / cofigure the script to run for particular period?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run a PHP file in a scheduled task (Windows Task Scheduler)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295386/how-to-run-a-php-file-in-a-scheduled-task-windows-task-scheduler)

Comment: You can find your answer here -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39805601/how-to-make-a-schedulercrone-in-php-on-windows-server/39805614#39805614

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Locate the php.exe executable on your system and pass it the name of the script file using the `-f` parameter.

Example:

```
C:\Xampp\php\php.exe -f C:\Xampp\htdocs\my_script.php
```

Reference:

- [Introduction to using PHP on the command line](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.introduction.php)
- [PHP command line options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php)

Comment: why above the code does not work for me. i write this code in and save it as `bat` file but no success

Comment: @Karthi Depending on how your PHP code is written, you may also need to set the working directory in the Task Scheduler.

Comment: After start the task my `php` file getting deleted, may i know the reason ?

Answer (score 21):

Here's how did it.

**Windows scheduler -> create a new task -> action tab -> Edit**

[image]

Comment: if you use laragon `C:\laragon\bin\php\VERSION_PHP\php.exe`

Answer (score 13):

At least I tried out some suggestions but it doesn't work so I tried this.

Use a bat file and schedule to execute that bat file.

For example in the bat file executephp.bat, write this

c:\xampp\php\php.exe -f c:\xampp\htdocs\do_something.php

save that bat file that contains that line.

Go to windows scheduler and create a new task and  in action tab, browse to point that executephp.bat and for start in -> direct to the directory u have that executephp.bat.

For example if u save the file under C:\xampp\htdocs put that C:\xampp\htdocs in the start in.

Remember to invoke the script even when the user is not logged on.

Everything is set and it will execute without problem.

Comment: .bat worked fine for me, php.exe directly on the command line would not work.

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco, Why would it not work? Did you ensure that you have surrounded the file names with quotes `"` ?

Answer (score 9):

You can use [PHP Command Line](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php) to execute it rather then trying to load it through the browser.

Under the actions tab, create a new action and:

- Program/Script: Point to your PHP.exe file
- Add Arguments: `-f /path/to/php/file.php`

Optionally you can make it start in the script's directory as well.

Answer (score 7):

create Schedule task 
Scheduler->Actions->Edit Action

if you have php file

```
Program/script: powershell 
Add arguments: curl http://localhost/demo/cron.php
```

if you have MVC/CMS URL

```
Program/script: powershell
Add arguments: curl http://localhost/demo/controller/method
```

Answer (score 5):

I just wanted to leave what i had to do to get this working for server 2012.  Which was what has previously been said but with added quotes and using the 'Add arguments' box.  So in Task Scheduler->Actions->Edit Action.

```
Program/script: "C:\xampp\php\php.exe"
Add arguments: -f "<full path and filename>"
Start in: <Path to file>
```

(I had to use 'start in' as i referred to class's within the script)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I did it.

In the Run box: `c:\location_of_my_php_installation\php.exe -f c:\location_of_my_php_file\php_file.php`

In the Start in box: `c:\location_of_my_php_installation\php.exe`

Answer (score 3):

you can directly call your local host url by using

```
explorer "http://localhost/yourFile.php"
```

Answer (score 3):

If the [answer given by Pekka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4701867/5202863) does not work (`C:\Xampp\php\php.exe -f C:\Xampp\htdocs\my_script.php`), make sure that you have the correct PHP extensions enabled as well as the correct `php.ini` file being used for the PHP version you are using.

I ran into this issue recently and resolved it. I was using PHP v5.4 to run my script.php that was nested within the top level PHP folder (v5.3). When I ran the `script.php`, from within the v5.4 folder, it was using the v5.3 `php.ini` file with different extensions, which caused the `script.php` to fail.

To fix this, here is what I did within the Task Scheduler : Actions tab

Program Script:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.4\php.exe"`

Add Arguements:

`-c "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.4\php.ini" -f "C:\Xampp\htdocs\script.php"`

[image: Task Schedulerer - Actions Script]

Using the `-c` option, you can specify which `php.ini` file should be used ([stackflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132978/php-command-line-php-ini-path-error)).

I verified which php was in use by following this [stackflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121360/command-line-php-mysql-connect-error).

In command line, type `php -m` to check which extensions are enabled.
Then, use `php --ini` to check which `.ini` file(s) is/are being read by PHP.

You may not be using the correct ini file for the PHP version you are using if you have multiple versions installed.

Comment: On error "The directory name is invalid. (0x8007010B)", remove the quotes of `Start in (optional)` field, doesn’t support them. [WINDOWS TASK SCHEDULER: THE DIRECTORY NAME IS INVALID. (0X8007010B)](http://matthewcevans.com/blog/2010/08/11/windows-task-scheduler-the-directory-name-is-invalid-0x8007010b/)

Answer (score 3):

You dont need a .bat file just set the options in the task scheduler:
[image: Windows Server Task Scheduler]

So here i've just pointed to the php.exe and then in the arguments the

-f fullpath2PHP file

The important bit is the **Start in** part - this should be the folder your php file (the one you want to run) sits in.
so for example:

**File location**
-f c:\inetpub\wwwroot\runthisplease\myFile.php

**Start in**
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\runthisplease\

You can test this by creating a windows shortcut (but you cannot schedule a shortcut link)

Comment: "Start in" not "Run in"

Comment: I think "this should be the folder" YOUR SCRIPT "sits in" not "your php".

Comment: This works but you need to surround the paths with quotes

Answer (score 1):

In the properties for your task in the Task Scheduler, change the account for which your script is running under to the SYSTEM account.

Beaware! You should ONLY do this for scripts you fully trust - Doing this elevates the privileges to of the script to beyond administrator.

Answer (score 1):

To create a scheduler in Windows, you need to:

1. Create `.bat` file on your server or system;
2. Type the following command in your`.bat` file:
    `“F:\xampp\php\php.exe” -f “F:/xampp/htdocs/sitefolder/test.php”;`
3. Set the scheduler time and file in your task scheduler in Windows.

Comment: please include command (or commands?) into the code-formatting wrappers (backticks) and check your quotation symbols: they should probably be either `"` or omitted at all