# Command Line PHP mysql_connect() Error

Tags: php, mysql, command-line

I am running a php page form the command line to update a mysql db once a php exec command has completed. This has been working OK.

However, I have just reinstalled my server and now the script is returning the following error when I run it on the command line:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()
```

The script runs fine in the browser which means mysql is installed OK. **How do I enable mysql in PHP to be run from the command line?**

Many thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, you can use

```
php -m
```

from the command-line, to check which extensions are enabled.

If mysql is not in the list, it means it's not enabled / loaded -- which is probably the case, here.

Then, you'll want to use

```
php --ini
```

to check which `.ini` file(s) is/are read by PHP.

Once you've found out which `php.ini` file is used, you'll have to edit it, and add something like this :

```
; configuration for php MySQL module
extension=mysql.so
```

To load the `mysql` extension.

Depending on your distribution, the might be a `.ini` file per extension *(Ubuntu does that, for instance)*.

If that's the case, you could also create a new `.ini` file (`mysql.ini` for instance) next to the other ones, and put the two lines I posted into that new file.

Comment: thanks for your response. I have tried this but have not had any luck. The problem is that when I run php --ini in the CLI, is states that my php.ini configuration file is located in /usr/local/lib, which is incorrect. Please see my new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132978/php-command-line-php-ini-path-error.

Comment: This was a life saver. For me, MySQL was throwing an `extension not found` error but only when run on the command line and adding this one line to php.ini fixed the problem.

Comment: Note: Now that PHP7 is out, make sure your command line is using the same PHP install as the one you have configured. Using `php --ini` on the command line I noticed that it was using PHP7 which I am not using on my sites yet.

Switching the command from `php /foo/bar.php` to `php5.6 /foo/bar.php` fixed the error for me

Answer (score 4):

Check the path to your PHP executable.  You didn't mention which OS this is under, but, for example, under OSX just running `php` executes the built-in PHP interpreter.  If you're using MAMP you'll need to run `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.2/bin/php` (or whatever your path is) to imitate what's running in your browser.

Alter the path to your web server's php accordingly (based on AMP installation, OS, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a short time ago (maybe it's the same problem for you):

I had specified my prefered php.ini in Apache's config. However, this obviously doesn't affect php in CLI. Check which `php.ini` is used by php: `php --ini`. Either modify it or choose a different config file by changing some of these:

> php.ini is searched in these locations (in order):
>
> - SAPI module specific location (PHPIniDir directive in Apache 2, -c command line option in CGI and CLI, php_ini parameter in NSAPI, PHP_INI_PATH environment variable in THTTPD)
> - The PHPRC environment variable. Before PHP 5.2.0 this was checked after the registry key mentioned below.
> - As of PHP 5.2.0, the location of the php.ini file can be set for different versions of PHP. The following registry keys are examined in order: [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP\x.y.z], [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP\x.y] and [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP\x], where x, y and z mean the PHP major, minor and release versions. If there is a value for IniFilePath in these keys, then the first one found will be used as the location of the php.ini (Windows only).
> - [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP], value of IniFilePath (Windows only).
> - Current working directory (except CLI)
> - The web server's directory (for SAPI modules), or directory of PHP (otherwise in Windows)
> - Windows directory (C:\windows or C:\winnt) (for Windows), or --with-config-file-path compile time option

I've just modified the PHPRC environment variable to my prefered location of `php.ini`.

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer was to change the first line in my script from '#!/usr/bin/php' to '#!/usr/bin/php -c /etc/php.ini'.

Even though 'php --ini' indicated it was processing the correct .ini file, it wasn't, so I had to force it on the header line of the script.