# PHP Command Line php.ini path error

Tags: command-line, php

I am trying to run some PHP pages on the command line but am running into a few problems with mysql and other PHP extensions.

Running `php --ini` produces the following output:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

When I run php on the command line it cannot find my php.ini file. This is because the path is incorrect. My php.ini is actually located in `/etc/php.ini` as stated in my `phpinfo();` file. PHP runs fine in the browser.

How do I change the path of my php.ini file for command line PHP?

I am running Apache2 (CentOS-5.5) and PHP 5.2.6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the `-c` option, you can specify which `php.ini` file should be used :

```
php -c /etc/php.ini your-php-script.php
```

As a reference, see the output of `php --help` :

```
$ php --help
Usage: php [options] [-f] <file> [--] [args...]
       php [options] -r <code> [--] [args...]
       php [options] [-B <begin_code>] -R <code> [-E <end_code>] [--] [args...]
       php [options] [-B <begin_code>] -F <file> [-E <end_code>] [--] [args...]
       php [options] -- [args...]
       php [options] -a

  -a               Run as interactive shell
  -c <path>|<file> Look for php.ini file in this directory
  -n               No php.ini file will be used
  -d foo[=bar]     Define INI entry foo with value 'bar'
  ...
```

Comment: What is "your-php-script.php" ? What do I have to enter?

Answer (score 0):

First update your sloacate database by using the command `updatedb`

Then try to locate php.ini file by using the command `php --ini`

I hope it'll update the slocate database and it will display the ini files loaded path.

```
[root@tamilan src]# php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php.d/apc.ini,
```

To run php with customized or other php.ini file use the below method

```
php -c /etc/php.ini your-php-script-file.php
```

Comment: What is "your-php-script.php" ? What do I have to enter?