# Running PHP file from command line

Tags: php, shell, batch-file, command-line

i am trying to achieve what is asked here, and i have tried the answer:
[How do I run a PHP script using windows schedule task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701861/how-do-i-run-a-php-script-using-windows-schedule-task)

I have got as far as making the .bat file, but when i run the file i get this:
http://puu.sh/8wbqj.png

I have tried just running the command in cmd, and get the same error. Any ideas why this is guys?

Comment: Quote the path if it contains spaces: `"C:\Program Files\iis express\PHP\v5.3\php.exe" …`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOS doesn't like spaces. Wrap it in quotes like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\iis express\PHP\v5.3\php.exe" -f "C:\htdocs\clients.php"
```