# fopen(), fwrite() function is not working in php

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks, fopen

Below is my code,

**test.php**

```
<?php
$prefixnew = "testnew";
$file1 = fopen("testnew.txt","w");
$content_wr_g = "Test sitest"
fwrite($file1,$content_wr_g);
fclose($file1);
?>
```

**test.bat**

```
@ECHO off


C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\php.exe -f  "C:\...\test.php"


popd
```

**UPDATE**

When i run (test.php) directly from browser it is working properly. if i run from scheduled tasks, it is not working.

I know very well about task scheduler steps to create a task. When i run set of update queries or delete queries means, it working nicely.

When i have code like `fopen(), fwrite()` etc it is not working

Comment: Can you show us what your scheduled task looks like? Is it a Cron job?

Comment: Created a task  in  windows "Task schduler" program

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701861/how-do-i-run-a-php-script-using-windows-schedule-task?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa]

Comment: @IbrahimHafiji no sir. Please see my updated question

Comment: Try setting a path to open the file. E.g `$file1 = fopen("C:\Users\username\Desktop\testnew.txt","w");`

Comment: The default directory when called from the browser is different than the default when called by the scheduler. As @IbrahimHafiji said, supply a complete path to the file you want to open (and you don't need the drive letter if it's on the same drive as your program).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using relative path, use absolute path to the file:

```
$file1 = fopen(__DIR__.'/testnew.txt', 'w');
```

I assume you are using `>= PHP 5.3`, if not try:

```
$file1 = fopen(dirname(__DIR__).'/testnew.txt', 'w');
```