# Triggering code at a certain time

Tags: php, events, time

Is it possible to tell PHP to execute a piece of code on a given date and time? For example, Blogger.com allows someone to set a blogpost to be published in the future (e.g. 12/12/14 6:00AM).

Can PHP do something similar?

(Sorry, I don't even know what the correct term for events like these would be to be able to even search for them! :( )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a cron job (or scheduled task on Windows); although they are typically used for reoccurring jobs.

If you're using a database, most platforms come with a scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule your action in your database and use a cronjob on your server or use a cron job service To run your actions.

https://www.setcronjob.com/

For example when you want to publish your blog in the future, you save your publish date in the future and set some sort of auto-publish bit.

Then every hour a PHP script is ran by a cronjob, this script checks the database for all blogs which need to be published.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to tell PHP to do this itself, since it would require a process to run forever to periodically call your PHP code. Thankfully though, there's a couple of things which do this:

1) Call a PHP script from a cron job, which then does any necessary work. If you don't have access to a crontab, you can periodically call this when a user pings your site instead, although that will be less reliable, of course.

2) Use [`at`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_at.htm). This works in basically the same way as cron on Linux systems, but will schedule once and at an exact time.

Answer (score 1):

for "triggering code at a certain time", cron works. But for something as simple as publishing an article at a specific time, it isn't needed. You can just store a publish date with your article. When displaying a list of articles you can adjust your query to something like `WHERE PUBLISH_DATE <= NOW()` and on the article page check if the article's publish date has passed before showing the article.

Comment: I contemplated that, but I thought it was "dirty". I guess it isn't. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On Unix-like systems, there's Cron. You can [manage Cron from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421020/use-php-to-create-edit-and-delete-crontab-jobs).

On Windows, there are scheduled tasks - you can also use [PHP to manage scheduled tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295386/how-to-run-a-php-file-in-a-scheduled-task-windows-task-scheduler).

Be careful with this though - it's kinda hard to test, and you may end up with a schedule that cripples your server.