# Configure Scheduled Task in wamp Server

Tags: php, wampserver

How can I configure a *scheduled task* in *wamp server*?

Comment: You cannot do that in WAMP, but you can do that in Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295386/how-to-run-a-php-file-in-a-scheduled-task-windows-task-scheduler?lq=1

Comment: @MihaiIorga That link would help more if he knows how to schedule a task in Windows already and is having issues making it work with PHP ^^