# Run PHP script constantly as windows service

Tags: php, windows, service

I have a PHP script that polls a database, checks for new entries, and, if a new entry is found, sends out a push notification to iOS devices.

I currently have the php script set up so if you refresh the page constantly, it does what I want. I could also set up a php or javascript refresh and just have the page open, but that wouldn't be very effective if I'm working with a remote server and can't tell what programs are open or when it restarts.

I'm thinking that a windows service would be the best solution to my issue, but I'm not sure how I can compile the php script into a windows service.

Does anybody have any suggestions? Worst case, I guess I could just write everything in C# and make a windows service out of that, but I'm sure there's an easier way.

Comment: Why was this downvoted without any responses?

Answer (score 2):

In Windows

You can use nssm.exe (Non-Sucking Service Manager). Download it here https://nssm.cc/

First, create your php script that polls a database:

```
<?php

/// script.php

while(true){
   //do some stuff here

   sleep(5); //wait for 5 seconds 
}

?>
```

Then in console, enter this command

```
nssm.exe install <service-name>
```

After that, In the Nssm service installer

1. In the path field, write path of your `php.exe`
2. In start up directory, write the location of your php script or your working directory
3. Lastly, in arguments field, write `script.php`

Then click the button install service.
You can now check your service in `windows service`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Windows Task Scheduler. It's not so powerful,like cron on unix-systems, but it will helps you. Here you can to find little more info about it
[How to run a PHP file in a scheduled task (Windows Task Scheduler)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295386/how-to-run-a-php-file-in-a-scheduled-task-windows-task-scheduler)

If you have(want) access to your script from web, you can use Windows Task Scheduler with wget, for example create new task with next path: wget.exe -O - -q -t 1 http://www.your-site.com/cron.php. Of cource, you must install wget to your local server.

Comment: But how often can task scheduler run this task? I'd like for it to be able to run at least twice a second.

Comment: It depends from version of your operating system. You can create test trigger and look a minimal time interval of repeat of the task. If repeat time isn't enough you, you can create two or more triggers.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use the program FireDaemon (AlwaysUp is an alternative). 
I installed PHP manually to C:\PHP and set the task to run

```
C:\PHP\php.exe C:\pathtophp\file.php
```