# Symfony2 background task

Tags: symfony, background, task

I would create a background task that loops continuously with Symfony2

I want to know how to do this

```
protected function execute(){
   while (true) {
      sleep(60);
      //------------ do some think
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, PHP doesn't have threading, so you won't be able to run that in parallel with your Symfony application.

Instead, create a cron job which executes that code via CLI.

Here's a pretty straight-forward intro to [cron jobs](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html).

If you're on a Windows server, set up a scheduled task. See [How to run a PHP file in a scheduled task (Windows Task Scheduler)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295386/how-to-run-a-php-file-in-a-scheduled-task-windows-task-scheduler).