# Is there a simple way to schedule a cron job without an addon/extension?

Tags: php, yii, cron, job-scheduling

I have a cron task running already on console, I want to set it to happen every day, is there a way to schedule it without any addon or extension?

I'm using Yii Framework 1.1 with Windows 7

Comment: Its an OS job, what's yours (windows, osx, linux ...) ???

Comment: GOOD POINT, gonna add the info there. Windows 7 running.

Comment: maybe interesting? [How to run a PHP file in a scheduled task (Windows Task Scheduler)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295386/how-to-run-a-php-file-in-a-scheduled-task-windows-task-scheduler)

Comment: also maybe interesting? [Using the Task Scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384006(v=vs.85).aspx). And: [Schtasks.exe - Enables an administrator to create, delete, query, change, run, and end scheduled tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Gonna look into it! Thank you very much Ryan!