# Execute PHP routines on Windows Server

Tags: php, windows, iis

I have a PHP scripts on Windows Server 2016 (IIS 10 PHP 7.1) And i would like to execute these scripts every x minutes. Is it possible to do something similar like SQL job? I can't use javascript because this need to be done without WEB Page. Somebody said its possible to execute PHP scripts without web server via CLI. Is it right? And lots of information about cron. But im not understand is it already integrated in to system or additional software?

Comment: If its windows then look at Task Scheduler to replace CRON

Comment: Duplicate of How to run a PHP file in a scheduled task (Windows Task Scheduler) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295386/how-to-run-a-php-file-in-a-scheduled-task-windows-task-scheduler ?